# Add marks on click

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I would like to add marks with clicks into the Vega view.

For example, in this density plot I would like to set these vertical rules with clicks:

[image: Density plot with three vertical rules]
[Link to Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemjEAGbUvg0yWLbqWCkATzgAnNAG1QapJhSpQDa4LQgnLglCRrCCkZeQBfJWRrAGtvYVk4RRBMayRZCAAzNmsEe0c4dLoLbwAJbIg4HDZlGySoNgZZTAg0FIY4JQhMSpbUAEZdMIBdJQL6tRpZMjRQYrcQDJo4QTVvNQKIIqTMCxxE9ABHBjTMOmcaUhAIkAAPGYWlle9iJEF27d39kCOTs9PLpSnTCCL5lIKVaq1MLQhSOZyuUCyJAIL4QHDCTAvN5wFrXKKxeY7PbeawMEFJLrWNjROAAESQEBg9jECgAbENrmM2BMpvc7vNFstVuhfChAZ9vD8mn8LolocMlKKKs17miMVj2r07AAOACsCj6Ym1CgATH1dRywkA)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible: Triggers can be used to update the data: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/triggers

In this example, points can be added by clicking into the Vega View:

[image]

[Link to Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-iCoQqxjYFkhTxARNU5NQoBRCRAObRLRAcHEUDYGjCoAYOBRFZAbBMUDogTQoCKJTCLkoVxktKiLZAbdK2nxhJMymLkMLAVUClrg4yAGIhlA9g0kA04TIgTQkAAlaNwAAiZSgHxwmHYkizA+KQ-QOCT4knMnL0DPF5e14gXlS0XQOtQaUxWldVpT5EkyTiU1MHNHUJSkICQDFSUZVAsUAG5pSYQDgNA8DSWQTBoNgy0QCeRDkMlTcQGZftoGKDJaJ7GhIi0dAUELZsvygBjtGbZjWO0eomhE91Mh40JvUqRFGKMKkMmCCw4CBGI2GQCx+xzZE4iQNEBOCNjxkLZQCS+Cp3FAb8yF-bQ7AcGBXRkcQaAiNB3lKGQAC9vjYNzlFKBE-T4uSQwUpSVJfNSkA068tPQfNcTTFiDKE6iTMsMJKismz0E8bxnxcVNnNc1B3LgLyfL8gLUyQZkygpej43QJi6w+CchLYbA1KMFR7AAZQkjJ+JAXq2LKvEXIUABhNQnzon9im0CI6T5Oz6AIIYXCowsNCimKiWKcEZGCJAmEib0DuCI6qg+BJLuu5BmQAUWZBk5tQdwQAQCwXreyEPomxQLsO8qQE8ixy1oj6xkaoajFJFj3pAUIiUhGRRoG3jmp6j4xv80GL0UGb1H+yyFr-EBluCPk8qwDatuo3b1Kve7QZOs6rrQVmt1urmQY9WrfvagGvp+17hc+wnAz5q7QfBzQWTQFwYcG7QWoR4XZE6zBuvR3GZeui9MCa8ZjtOyIlRKCAHNK-GzY5gB5UhlBOnAqoJybifesnrMW8I4BWtaYHp7avIhxXodWWHgueNqkZRtGRv11BucpOgTfqe3Iid75XfdwHptm0nMnJpaA+p2nMBD6j5chpWxOyw6KRkqEASBEFnivSo4FIJ8pMstRMW0YgWJ0ELQ3QBA1HBXadEkZj6UZDkGQQPlJUoANKBk6UAF49+lAByVROoPxyQCrGttGAJBAIsZ2iIP5kD6kZk18lBDsMVcR775A-AmfwIb8miunhEAA). Important are the signal `addMark` that listens on clicks and the trigger that is added to the input data `source_0`. The signal passes the data as it is stored in the dataset.

Triggers can also be used to drag marks, as in this example that builds on the first:

[image]

[Link to editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-dHY0yHo8ZMhweUkik0hk8wpykLAnLtBBAggmGxov4gqEKsY2BZMIGZDDVFLUKATQkQIOuS0QHBxFBoWFQAwcCaZyA2CYoHR4f2QBjSmgXJQrt3FdEN1uMsLRSZlBPO2OAqoFIuT9oAMRDKB7BpIBpMmRgmhIABKDZwAAImUUAfDgmDsJIx7FNu6A4O24jXjIGhgRBUEvBuEBeKkR4gFauJ4laeJenihripKcTGmmUYBk8xEESAtr2mRVoANyUviJFkRRErIJgNGmnRMZdoxVosd+IBqmgoDQMUGQyQekRaOgKBjuuclQAp2jwspwSqYsTTGTmmTaaEBaVKyilGLKGThuIcBgjEbDIBYsnDhy7LxFy+mGepMj-JYYSJO4cm4cU2h2A4MBZjIyYRGg7ylDIABe3xsElyilCyxa6bZlb2RYTk-KhrlIO5G6Dt5nKCiACoqdo9RjkFXzSjhZB4donjeChLhPCACVhMlcBpRlWU5QNSBqlihZmTp6BKUuHxXk1bDYK5RgqPYADK5kZHpIDbapI1CjQigAMJqMhHkdV14RwIqhrRfQBBDC4tpSRo5WVTCxQQKNIDBEgTCRAWf3BADP4fAkENQyAyBqgAomqyo3ag7gIxYKNo52GNnYo4P-YDqUWGhMkY2M8ktugh0SjQq3oKEMKdjIx17Qt0lbR8J3ZYDUGXddePhZ1kUPU9PVYG9H1fT9MFw4DwOg5DaAK9Df6q8TubTTjjOYwg2Oo3rBNlprkMk2T6o7lT+3aEt9OM7I62YJtbM82b8NQZgNPjDISuRK6JQQLFqCnUDIORAA8qQyjAzgE38+dChXeowuZBF+ERE9L0wNLn1jqTmhW5TqzUwdRgO+jQNwCz3P2B7ifexk9R+xHwTR98ccJybKfoyL90gFnwSGpLmB51Jhfk9bA13f90rWQixKZc8MGVHApDIQWICJDWdYNqgUIMAD306OIFJ2JobA6AfagA3ODx4gAfHiF8nzfR+IGwpBGHOC7YkRFgY6CQAORqmAVINUhoWIUipC6cQQDDTAMCOAwIUDbSMmZKsBe6AaRAlBOCCuq9QDryvFvXe9Zgjv2PlfSQMhf5xAyJGLMzIgA)

---

Applied to the example of my initial question, the final spec looks like:

[image]

[Link to Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/8e059f0da4ec127819217c4d99325710/density_drag_split.vg.json)